# Merge [http-post] and [post]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[http-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-post) seems to be a duplicate of [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post). Can it be merged, and made into a synonym?